# Spring Webapp behind Apache Web Server - Secured by CAS

Tags: spring-security, apache, cas

I have a Webapp that is secured using Spring Security CAS. The CAS Server and the Webapp sit behind a web server for reverse proxy (named url). The webapp uses ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource to authenticate dynamic service urls. The problem I have is that Service Ticket validations are failing because the url supplied during validation does not match the url provided when the ticket was created. The set up works without the webserver when systems are connected using https://:/.

The issue seems to be that the web server modifies the HttpServletRequest when redirecting to the webapp where in it looses the "named url" information and is substituted with the  and . The service ticket is obtained using the named url via "?service=" during login.

Any possible solution? Can apache reroute request without modifying it, especially for applications that are self identifying or for security reasons where CAS is trying to record the client IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have outlined a few options below:

**Setup the Reverse Proxy**

According to the Javadoc of [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29): the HttpServletRequest.getServerName() will be:

> the value of the part before ':' in the Host header value, if any, or
>   the resolved server name, or the server IP address.

This means you can configure your proxy to ensure the Host Header is set properly (Note Some containers like WebSphere do not honor the specification though).

**Override using the Container Configuration**

Many servers have a setup that can override this value in the event you are using a reverse proxy. There is a pretty decent [thread on the Spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?108494-Spring-security-s-HTTPS-issue-with-load-balance/) with a bit more information on it that I have summarized below.

If you are using Tomcat, I'd refer to the [Reverse Proxy setup page](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html). One method of configuration would be to configure the [Http Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) to have the proxyName attribute to override the value returned by HttpServletRequest.getServerName() and proxyPort to override the value returned by HttpServletRequest.getServerPort(). An example configuration might look like:

**server.xml**

```
<Connector scheme="https" secure="true" 
    proxyPort="443" proxyName="example.com"
    port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3"
    redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="750" 
    connectionTimeout="20000" />
```

Websphere has a few [custom properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rweb_custom_props.html) that do the same thing.

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extractHostHeaderPort = true
trusthostheaderport = true
httpsIndicatorHeader = com.ibm.ws.httpsIndicatorHeader
```

If you are not using either of these containers or need to support multiple domains, you will need to consult your containers documentation.

**Custom AuthenticationDetailsSource**

Of course Spring Security is pretty flexible, so you can always provide a custom implementation of AuthenticationDetailsSource that returns an instance of ServiceAuthenticationDetails that looks up the service URL in any way you wish.